# Appending an Iframe within an Iframe to a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to append and Iframe with an Iframe to a particular div depends upon a condition.,

```
if(condtion true) {
    divStr= '<div id='somedivid'> <iframe id='somefrmid' class="frmClass"  frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';
    $('#somewindowDiv').append(divStr);
    alert('Opening in inner Frame');
    $('#somewindowDiv').find('.frmClass').contents().find('body').append('<iframe id='somefrmid' class="frmClass" frameborder="0" src='+url+'></iframe>');                
}
else {
      divStr= '<div id='somedivid' ><iframe id='somefrmid' class="frmClass" frameborder="0" src='+url+'></iframe></div>';
      $('#somewindowDiv').append(divStr);   
  }
```

When the alert('Opening in inner Frame'); is there in the If condtion then in the second iFrame the respected src is getting opened, when I remove the alert it is not opening.And also when I debug the script through fire bug with or without alert it opened successfully.

SO, it seems like,since I'm continously appdending to the div,DOM is not getting updated immediately, How can I append the second iframe to it? Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes within a single quoted string `'<iframe id='somefrmid' ...` it should have been `'<iframe id="somefrmid" ...`

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have updated as you suggested, Still the same problem.  As I mentioned the "somewindowDiv" is not getting updated in the DOM. After the divStr appened to the div I am appending one more iFrame these change is not updated at run time.

Comment: It's not just there, that was an example, all your code is full of these. Share your code and markup in http://jsfiddle.net/